# macOS Mojave - Get "Segmentation fault: 11" when trying to run airport

Tags: terminal, wifi, airport, mojave

As the title suggests, when I run the command `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport en0 sniff 6` in Terminal where `en0` is my Wi-Fi interface and `6` is the channel I am sniffing; I am now getting an error message reading `Segmentation fault: 11` almost instantly. This has never been a problem before updating to macOS Mojave (10.14) but is a reoccurring problem with the new update despite reboots, NVRAM resets etc.

My question is: has anybody else experienced this problem before? If so, are there any solutions or is it something that we must hope Apple will fix in a future release of macOS?

Thank you in advance for any help,

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: were you able to fix this, I'm having the same problem on 10.14.1 beta

Comment: @acrogenesis Unfortunately not. Hopefully it's something which will be fixed in a future release of Mojave. For now, I'm using `tcpdump` as suggested below but would like to move back to the `airport` command as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced with this problem, when try to dump traffic from interface. Possible solutions:

- use `tcpdump` with writing to file, like suggested [below](https://louisabraham.github.io/articles/WPA-wifi-cracking-MBP.html)
- use Wireshark for capturing traffic from this interface

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was aware that other tools like the ones you mentioned were capable of dumping traffic; however, my question pertained to the fixing of the problem with the `airport` command in particular. Either way, thank you for suggesting `tcpdump` as a reasonable alternative for anyone else looking in the future. I too, will be using `tcpdump` until Apple fixes the `airport` issue. Thanks once again! Best

Comment: Sadly, airport seems to be the only option to sniff specific multicast messages. This worked fine with airport, but these messages does not show up when using tcpdump or wireshark.

Comment: How are you using `tcpdump` in exchange of `airport en0 sniff 6`?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found an executable file on /usr/libexec/airportd, it works properly as previous versions.

Comment: Good find, however I'm still having the same problem. Even if I run `/usr/libexec/airportd en0 sniff 6` I still get the same `Segmentation fault: 11` error